# Amarino Bluetooth Connectivity

Tags: android

I am working with Aurdino and Amarino task. I am able to connect with Aurdino and I can send data to Aurdino from Android app. In the same way how I can access the data from  Aurdino which I supposed to send to Android app(accessing data from aurdino means not the same data which I have sent from android app to aurdino). Aurdino can contain different data and  I want to access that. Please help me

Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the Bluetooth RX to your Arduino TX (**after** uploading your sketch), you should be able to the data that is coming from Android with normal Serial operations. Here is an example sketch, that will turn LED on port 13 on if '1' is received otherwise it will be turned off
[see this for a tutorial](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Tutorial01)

You can also use a SoftSerial port

```
char val; 
int ledpin = 13; 
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);  
  Serial.begin(9600);       
}
void loop() {
  if( Serial.available() )      
  {
    val = Serial.read();        
    Serial.println(val);
  }

  if( val == '1' )              
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH); 
  } else { 
    digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);  
  }
  delay(100);                   
}
```